# Redirect the output of netstat to a file?

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection, netstat

I'm trying to redirect the output of `netstat` to a file and it doesn't work.

Initially I tried:

```
runas /noprofile /user:xxxxx\administrator "netstat -a -b > C:\temp\file.txt"
```

Then I read somewhere that the output of netstat is sent to std.err:

```
runas /noprofile /user:xxxxx\administrator "netstat -a -b 2>C:\temp\file.txt"
```

I've also tried it this way:

```
runas /noprofile /user:xxxxx\administrator "netstat -ab 2> C:\temp\file.txt"
```

None of these seem to result in the file `C:\temp\file.txt` being populated with the output.

Comment: actually using `1>` instead only worked on my machine, not on the user's machine. :-p

Comment: Is the `C:\temp\file.txt` created by any or all of the above commands, with nothing written to it?  Does the output of the `netstat` command appear on the screen (or anywhere else)?  Have you tried this with a simple command, like `dir`, `date /t`, `hostname`, or `ping 127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest trying:

```
runas /noprofile /user:xxxxx\administrator "netstat -a -b" > C:\temp\file.txt
```

or:

```
runas /noprofile /user:xxxxx\administrator "netstat -a -b" 2> C:\temp\file.txt
```

i.e., redirect the output of the `runas` command (which should encompass the output of the `netstat` command) rather than redirecting the output of the `netstat` command directly.

Answer (score -1):

From an **elevated command prompt** use the following:

```
netstat -a -b > C:\netstat.txt
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.